# weblogic.rmi.extensions.DisconnectMonitorUnavailableException: Could not register a DisconnectListener for [null]

Tags: weblogic

After restarting the host, start the application error under weblogic.The error message is as follows:

> JENNIFER SysProf libjennifer20.so(sl) shared library loaded  failed:
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jennifer20 in java.library.path
>   <2018-10-15 上午11时04分55秒 GMT+08:00>   
>     <2018-10-15
>   上午11时05分05秒 GMT+08:00>      <2018-10-15 上午11时05分05秒 GMT+08:00> 
>      
>   <2018-10-15 上午11时05分05秒 GMT+08:00>
>
> There are 1 nested errors:
>
> weblogic.rmi.extensions.DisconnectMonitorUnavailableException: Could
>   not register a DisconnectListener for [null]
>           at weblogic.rmi.extensions.DisconnectMonitorListImpl.addDisconnectListener(DisconnectMonitorListImpl.java:83)
>           at weblogic.security.utils.AdminServerListener.startDisconnectListener(AdminServerListener.java:118)
>           at weblogic.security.utils.AdminServerListener.startListening(AdminServerListener.java:100)
>           at weblogic.security.utils.AdminServerListener.start(AdminServerListener.java:73)
>           at weblogic.server.AdminServerListenerService.initializeAdminServerListener(AdminServerListenerService.java:31)
>           at weblogic.server.AdminServerListenerService.start(AdminServerListenerService.java:24)
>           at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
>           at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
>           at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was due to having security filter in weblogic domain. I was added some connection filter rules but forgot to add all machine IPs to be allowed.
You can find all your machine IPs and then add them in 
[WL-domain-name]>Security>Filtere>Connection Filter Rules:

localhost * * allow t3 t3s
127.0.0.1 * * allow t3 t3s
192.168.0.3 * * allow t3 t3s
[IP4] * * allow t3 t3s
...
[IPn] * * allow t3 t3s